# How to make simple Json Post in Asp.net with parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, xamarin.forms

I Have logic App running in `Azure` that connect to on premise database , i already succesfull to Post data via `xamarin` forms but now to make the logic apps link more safety i want to create `Web Api` that handle the post request. And when I am try to test it via postman it keep getting this message

> "Message": "The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'."

I already make post code in the `Asp.net` and I don't know why its said that my `Asp.net` don't support `html` method Post ? here is my full Post Source Code

```
string sUrl = "My Logic Apps Link";
string sContentType = "application/json"; // or application/xml
// POST api/<controller>
public async void Post(string param1, string param2, string param3)
{
    JObject oJsonObject = new JObject();

    oJsonObject.Add("param1", param1);
    oJsonObject.Add("param2", param2);
    oJsonObject.Add("param3", param3);

    HttpClient oHttpClient = new HttpClient();
    var oTaskPostAsync = await oHttpClient.PostAsync(sUrl, new StringContent(oJsonObject.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, sContentType));

    if (oTaskPostAsync.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        string content = await oTaskPostAsync.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        content.ToString();
    }
}
```

please review my code and tell me where is my mistake , because when im try this in xamarin.forms it works and here is the postman body request

```
{
    "param1":"value",
    "param2":"value",
    "param3":"value"
}
```

i try with get method and its return value with the parameter hard coded

```
[Route("postdata")]
// GET api/Post
public string Get()
{
    var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://xxx-xx.southeastasia.logic.azure.com");
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
        {
            param1 = "value",
            param2 = "value",
            param3 = "value"
        });
        streamWriter.Write(json);
    }

    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        return result;
    }
}
```

but i dont know why the post mode always get error message

```
// GET api/Post
public string Post(string type, string type1, string email )
{
    var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://xxxx-xx.southeastasia.logic.azure.com");
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
        {
            param1 = type,
            param2 = type1,
            param3 = email
        });

        streamWriter.Write(json);
    }

    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Why that happen ? I'm still very very new in asp.net, can you tell me where is the part that I'm wrong thanks

Comment: It is fairly impossible to say without knowing the backend. The URL you're posting to now does not support the POST verb. So check that you are hitting the right endpoint _or_ check that this endpoint accepts POST requests.

Comment: Is this part of a web API controller? Is it web API v2? It _should_ use convention-based routing to send POST requests to a method called Post, unless you change something. Please show your routing config and also check you're calling the right URL - can you show the format of the URL you're using? Better still, show the code you're using to make the request.

Comment: Better use RestSharp. Also mention the controller code in there.

Comment: @ADyson its Azure Mobile App Custom Controller, im able to get the value with get method in postman and hardcode the parameter but when i create the post method and try it on postman its always return with same error code and my url is something like this https://xxxx-xx.southeastasia.logic.azure.com

Comment: @GeraldVersluis i updated my question can you figure this out ? thanks

Comment: Hang on, which thing are you using to make the reques to, from Postman? You have two methods here called "Post". It seems like one of them calls the other using WebRequest. So I assume that from Postman you're calling the method called "Post" at the bottom of the question? And is it true that when you renamed this method "Get", it worked fine? Notice on your "Get" method you have a Route attribute, but on the version named "Post" you do not. Also have you tried decorating it with a [HttpPost] attribute as well?

Comment: yes in the postman there is many selected request method when i select GET then click Send its work fine but when im select POST and write the parameter in body it will return with error message,i already try to add  [HttpPost] above the Post Method in the Asp.Net but i dont know why its still return error message. Maybe thats not how we write Post method ?

Comment: Can you show the whole class definition where this is contained, please? And you're routing config? And the full URL you're using in Postman?

Comment: fixed i forgot to add route in my method thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the attribute to the action:

```
[HttpPost]
public async void Post(string param1, string param2, string param3)
```

And if you sending the parameter via body you need to tell your action:

```
[HttpPost]
public async void Post([FromBody]YourClass params)
```

Take a look at this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-1

Comment: and dont forget to add route in your method